# Use multiple useState hook vs use single useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I want to refactor my old personal react project from class components to react hooks. My question is what is the best practice of using `useState` hooks, is that use multiple `useState` per UI state or use single object as state on `useState` hooks? Is using multiple `useState` is affecting the react app performance?

Comment: There's no clear-cut solution; as a rule of thumb I'd use separate state hooks for data that changes independently. For instance if you have a table displaying server data, I'd use one hook to store the filtering and sorting settings, and a second one to store the table data itself.

Comment: In my opinion, avoid using state as much as possible will make your app perform better (avoid unnecessary rendering) and less complicated

Comment: Using separate useState hooks is the best way, which can help you to track state changes separately and will make your app perform better.